# Is a factory of classes a valid javascript pattern?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

Some time ago I learnt a lot of design-patters, specially creational ones.
After some time, I found myself using a patter that I though existed, but when I tried to search about it I didn't found any reference. Basically it is a small modification of a factory which takes advantages of the closures to resolve dependencies of a class. Actually, it is a factory of classes. Let's me illustrate this with a bit of code:

```
function Factory(depA,depB){

    function MyClass(something){
        this.something = something;
    }

    MyClass.prototype.methodA(){ // use depA}
    MyClass.prototype.methodB(){ // use depB}

    return MyClass
}
```

Let's assume that depA is a database and depB is a logger. Then you can use the factory like this

```
var BindedClass = Factory(database,logger);
var instance = new BindedClass(something);
```

I find this patter very useful for injecting common dependencies, without loosing the control of how the class is actually instantiated.

However, this has some problems. For example, one of the things that made me realize that this is not so common is that JSDoc does not have support at all for this kind of pattern.

Is it a bad pattern? I can't find any disadvantage on it apart from less modularization and non-working documentation tools.

Comment: I suppose it has some meaning if you store `BindedClass` somewhere and call `new BindedClass()` multiple times. If you just plan to execute those two lines in succession all the time, then you may as well have `Factory` take `something` as an argument and have it return a plain object.

Comment: Dear @JLRishe the idea is indeed to do that. In any case, using a class also has several advantages over a POJO even if you are going to just run those two lines close to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a totally accepted pattern. However we rarely call it a "factory", more common is just "module" - in this case with dependency injection. Many module systems like AMD use this pattern.

You should however ensure that the factory produces a singleton - i.e. `Factory` should not be called multiple times and create multiple similar classes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Bergi. Why do you think it should be a singleton? What if I want to use the Factory to create several classes with different dependences injected? Do you know any way to document this successfully with JSDoc? Thanks!

Comment: Creating several alike classes will cause issues with inheritance relationships and duplicate methods that could be shared. I recommend to let each class inherit from a public common baseclass in such cases, if you really need this. You might also want to consider putting the dependency injection in the instance creation process if you need a few instances with different dependencies. (And of course: in your testing environment it's totally fine to call the factory multiple times to test the DI)

Comment: No, I have no idea about JSDoc, I only have often heard it to be inadequate for more complex cases.

Comment: Do you know any other alternative?